# Jasper Report can't be exported to PDF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jasper-reports

I'm trying to export a jasper report to PDF but it doesn't work.

this is the code that I'm using.
**Note:** contextPath variable contains the actual context. It has the value of the absolute path to my .war file

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   8.5\webapps\myWarFile\

```
String sourceFileName = 
    contextPath + "WEB-INF/classes/report/ClsReportBean.jasper";
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(sourceFileName, "C://sample_report.pdf", 
    parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstDataSource));
```

the problem is when I try to export the report to PDF. This is the error message.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error saving file:
>   C:\sample_report.pdf.

[image: Error part 1]
[image: Error part 2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Please post the full stacktrace as text instead of picture. 2. Try to use another path to export file as the application may not be able to write in C drive

Comment: As @samabcde said, if it's a permission issue try saving in Tomcat's temp dir and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using this code ...

```
try {

   File file = new File(exportPdfPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            LOGGER.info("creating folder");
            file.mkdir();
            file.setWritable(true);
        }


        JasperPrint something = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstDataSource));
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(exportPdfPath+"/test.pdf")); 
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(something, output); 
            output.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile` does not generate a PDF but a serialized filled report object.  For some reason the filled report has a reference to a `DefaultJasperReportsContext` instance, which is not serializable.  That shouldn't happen, but to understand why it does we would need more details on the case.

But if you want to generate a PDF, you don't need to serialize the filled report.  You can do the following to directly generate the PDF:

```
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile(sourceFileName, "C://sample_report.pdf", 
    parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstDataSource));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but now I got this error message 
**net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:** Error saving file: C://sample_report.pdf

cause by ...
**Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext**

Comment: Can you post the full exception stacktrace?